# How do I push a target (into a pit or something)?

Tags: hitman-absolution

In Hitman: Absolution, how do I push a target (into a pit or something) using a controller & keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Please keep in mind that here in the Arqade, a certain level of research is expected of the user. We like to help, but if a question shows no research effort, it is an easy candidate for down-voting. If I can get the answer up as the first hit on google in 15 seconds, this has not shown research effort. Perhaps you should get into the habit of looking for providing your own research. These questions tend to attract better attention, and if you find the answer, you can still post the question - but with your own answer. This will help future users, and earn you more rep at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done if the target is next to a ledge that is specifically made for pushing enemies over — in other words, it has to be *scripted*. To do this, just press the action key (whatever you have it binded to) while in front of the target.